# Linear Functions of Independent Random Variables: What's the value of b?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{25}$ are independent random variables from N$(1, 4)$. 
$Y = aX + b$, where $a$ ($a > 0$) and $b$ are constants. $X = \frac{1}{25} \sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i$. We know that $Y$ is a standard normal random variable.

What's the value of $b$?

Comment: The post did not say what $X$ is. The sum of the $X_i$? The sum divided by $25$?

Comment: The sum divided by 25, my mistake!

Comment: $X$ has mean $1$ and variance $4/25$. So $(a)(1)+b=0$, $(a^2)(4/25)=1$. We get $a=5/2$, so $b=-5/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $X_i \sim N(1,4)$, gives $\sum_i X_i \sim N(25, 100)$, hence $X = \frac 1{25}\sum_i X_i \sim N(1,\frac{4}{25})$. This implies that $aX \sim N(a,\frac{4}{25}a^2)$ and $aX + b \sim N(a+b, \frac{4}{25}a^2)$. If $aX+ b \sim N(0,1)$, this implies 
$$ \frac{4}{25}a^2 = 1, \qquad a +b = 0$$
as $a > 0$, $\frac{4}{25}a^2 = 1$ gives $a = \frac 52$, hence $b = -a = -\frac 52$.

Comment: No, the given Variance $\color{red}4$ of $X$, is in $aX + b \sim N(a+b, {\color{red}4}a^2)$

Comment: According to my answer sheet, the correct answer is b = -2.5, but I follow your reasoning, so I'm not sure what happened

Comment: Ah .. did not see your comment above .. one moment .

Comment: Corrected.${}{}{}$